# Android get page source inside loop

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android programming. When my app starts it crashed.
maybe this is a loop problem.
app works fine when i remove code which get source from page

is it possible to get page source inside loop, for example every minute?

Comment: You have to create the view before accessing any elements. Kind of like, you have to "peel the banana, before eating it".

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the most frequent errors observed here

With this line

```
TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

you are trying to access a view before the content view has been set. So you'll have to move this line like

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
TextView mTextView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_security_system);
    mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
```

Comment: ok and now i have this error this line: mTextView.setText(response); can not resolve symbol mTextView

Comment: Yeah you needed to separate declaration from definition ... I should have mentioned that

Comment: everything is good but this looping not working when phone screen goes off. can u help me?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea about MediaPlayer looping. Please ask a new question